# Qt Multimedia doesn't seem to work on Touch

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt, ubuntu-sdk, camera

Using Qt package 'Multimedia' to get cameras on the bq phone:

```
QList<QCameraInfo> cameras = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();
```

cameras.size() always returns zero.

Host 14.04, target 14.10, Qt 5.3.0.
*.apparmor from core camera-app.

Is it implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just verified and seems QCameraInfo::availableCameras() always returns an empty list indeed. This seems like a bug. I've reported it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtmultimedia-opensource-src/+bug/1438072

Please confirm and add any other findings you might have related to QCamera and C++.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have all dependencies installed. They are:

> qtmultimedia5-dev

_

> libqt5multimedia5-plugins

Ex:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5-plugins
```

Comment: Touch is discontinued.